# moving Sprite on X-axis while rotating it in swift by rotating device

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, accelerometer

I'm trying to make my sprite move side to side along the X-axis while it rotates as if its rolling. This is what I tried previously;

```
var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(0.05, duration: 1)
    let rerotate = SKAction.reversedAction(rotate)
    if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler:{
            data, error in
            let currentX = self.steve.position.x
            if data!.acceleration.x < 0 {
                self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 500)
                //self.rolling = true
                //self.steve.removeAllActions()
                self.steve.runAction(rotate)
            }
            else if data!.acceleration.x > 0 {
                self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data!.acceleration.x * 500)
                //self.rolling = true
               // self.steve.removeAllActions()
                self.steve.runAction(rerotate())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

however after a couple of times, this method becomes unresponsive and my sprite moves to the left and doesn't move upon the rotation of the device. Another approach to what I'm trying to accomplish would be greatly appreciated. Thank you